# Get request to Mongodb returns empty response to IP address, same code on localhost works as expected

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, docker-compose

Trying to Dockerize a Node Express Mongo app, running locally front and backend communicates fine. In Docker both front and back servers starts. The landing page of the app loads up but getting and creating data fails.

Connection to Mongo is below - port 27017 is already used by another container so I expose port 27027

```
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://mongo:27027/report",
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
```

In the dockerfile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g nodemon
EXPOSE 5600
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"  ]
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    container_name: report-node
    restart: always
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8880:8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27027:27017
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

the get request to retrieve data is

```
const API_URL = 'http://192.168.141.175:5600';

export default {
    getReports() {
        return ezFetch.get(`${API_URL}/api/report/list`)
},
```

The error returned is

> GET http://192.168.141.175:5600/api/report/list
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The same code above with localhost in mongoose.connect and in the API_URL succeeds in getting and creating.. why will this not connect in Docker?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work with 2 revisions. Because the API and client are in a single container the docker-compose has to expose both ports. the 1st is for the client and 2nd is for the API

```
ports:
  - 8888:8080
  - 5600:5600
```

and yes as in Mihai's answer the API_URL should remain at localhost

> const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5600'

'

Answer (score 0):

When working with containers I would avoid using IP's. Use instead the name of the container. IP's can change and that is up to the docker engine.

Also your Dockerfile exposes a port (5600), but you are mapping a different port in your docker-compose.